# RestSharp How to display json on page

Tags: restsharp

I have a call to a service that returns some json.

```
 {
"channels": {
    "22802056": {
        "id": "22802056",
        "title": "TV Live 1",
        "url": "http://www.ustream.tv/channel/XBccccHefj",
        "tiny_url": "http://ustre.am/1xss6",
        "broadcast_urls": [
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega06.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/22802ccc",
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega13.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/22802ccc",
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega15.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/22802ccc"
        ],
        "status": "offline",
        "description": "",
        "owner": {
            "id": "37134940",
            "username": "xxxx_align",
            "picture": "https://ustvstaticcdn1-a.akamaihd.net/images/defaults/user_48x48:3.png"
        },
        "authority": {
            "reason": "own"
        },
        "default": true
    },
    "22802058": {
        "id": "22802058",
        "title": "TV Live 2",
        "url": "http://www.ustream.tv/channel/DjAccczbPJ",
        "tiny_url": "http://ustre.am/1ssR8",
        "broadcast_urls": [
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega06.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/228020ccc",
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega13.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/228020ccc",
            "rtmp://sjc-uhs-omega15.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/228020ccc"
        ],
        "status": "offline",
        "description": "",
        "owner": {
            "id": "37134940",
            "username": "xxxx_align",
            "picture": "https://ustvstaticcdn1-a.akamaihd.net/images/defaults/user_48x48:3.png"
        },
        "authority": {
            "reason": "own"
        }
    }
},
"paging": {
    "actual": {
        "href": "https://api.ustream.tv/users/self/channels.json?p=1"
    }
}
}
```

This gets me the JSON:

```
IRestResponse jsonResponse = client.Execute(request);
```

In the example above there are only two channels displayed. In reality there are dozens of channels.  How can I use this object and display all the channels and future channels on a page?  If I paste this as a class in Visual Studio it creates a seperate class for each channel?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use NewtonSoft json.net to get this to work for me.

```
string jsonResult = LoadJson();

        dynamic objStreams = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
        var channelsData = ((JObject)objStreams.channels).Children();
        foreach(JToken channelToken in channelsData)
        {
            var channeldeatils = channelToken.Children();
            foreach (JToken properties in channeldeatils)
            {
                lstBox.Items.Add("ID : " + properties["id"].ToString());
                lstBox.Items.Add("Title : " + properties["title"].ToString());
                lstBox.Items.Add("URL : " + properties["url"].ToString());
                lstBox.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
```